# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5312), found shape=(None, 168)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am unable to train the model. Someone, please help!!!!!
Here is the code I am trying. While running **model_history = model_final.fit([X_weather, X_soil], y,batch_size=16, epochs=100)** I am getting this error.

```
X_weather.shape
(25345, 168)
X_soil.shape
(25345, 66)
```

````
input1 = Input(shape=(168,1))
input2 = Input(shape=(66,1))
model_1D = Conv1D(16, kernel_size= 9 , strides=1, activation='relu')(input1)
model_1D = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides=2)(model_1D)
model_1D = Conv1D(32, kernel_size= 3 , strides=1, activation='relu')(model_1D)
model_1D = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides=2)(model_1D)
model_1D = Conv1D(48, kernel_size= 3 , strides=1, activation='relu')(model_1D)
model_1D = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides=2)(model_1D)
model_1D = Conv1D(64, kernel_size= 3 , strides=1, activation='relu')(model_1D)
model_1D = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(pool_size= 2, strides=2)(model_1D)
model_1D = Flatten()(model_1D)
model_s = Dense(10 , activation='relu')(input2)
model_s = Dense(10 , activation='relu')(model_s)
model_s = Flatten()(model_s)
merged = Concatenate()([model_1D, model_s])
output = Dense(128, activation='relu')(merged)
output = Dense(32 , activation='relu')(output)
output = Dense(1 , activation='relu')(output)
model_final = Model(inputs=[model_1D, model_s], outputs=[output])

model_final.compile(
    optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.02,rho=0.9,epsilon=None,decay=0),
    loss = 'mean_squared_error',
    metrics=['accuracy']
    
)

model_history = model_final.fit([X_weather, X_soil], y,batch_size=16, epochs=100)```
````

Comment: This model does not match the error message, are you sure its the right code triggering this error?

Comment: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_5" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512), found shape=(None, 168)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please show us a minimal reproducible example with code and data so we can reproduce and help.
See [MRE]

Comment: You need to use your `Input` layers as the model's input (input1, input2). You're using layers made after the input layers as input, which is the most glaring problem I see.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Changing `model_final = Model(inputs=[model_1D, model_s], outputs=[output])` to `model_final = Model(inputs=[input1, input], outputs=[output])` solved the issue. Thank you @Djinn.